# Is it possible to have 1 matplotlib slider control 2 different matplotlib animations?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, matplotlib-widget, matplotlib-animation

If anyone has any experience doing this, please let me know as I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), before posting a question!

Comment: Sorry I haven't posted any code, there weren't any projects online or questions about this online, and I'm trying to implement this to a bigger project, so just curious if this is even possible.